# How to configure Spring XD JMS source to use DefaultMessageListenerContainer?

Tags: spring-xd

To make the JMS topic subscription durable, it seems I need to make sure

1. DefaultMessageListenerContainer (instead of the default
   SimpleMessageListenerContainer) is used
2. stream definition contains "durableSubscription=true acknowledge=transacted subscriptionName=xxxx pubSub=true"

I managed to enable 'dmlc' by specifying spring.profiles.active in xd-singlenode.bat but is there a better way such as using properties or yml?

***xd-singlenode.bat***

> set SPRING_XD_OPTS=-D**spring.profiles.active=singlenode,dmlc**
>   -Dspring.application.name=singlenode -Dlogging.config=%XD_CONFIG_LOCATION%/xd-singlenode-logback.groovy -Dxd.home=%XD_HOME%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `JmsSourceModuleOptionsMetadata` source code we have:

```
public String[] profilesToActivate() {
    if ("transacted".equals(this.acknowledge)) {
        return new String[] { "dmlc" };
    }
    else {
        return new String[] { "smlc" };
    }
}
```

So, looks like your `acknowledge=transacted` is enough to go ahead with the

```
container-class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"
```

in the JMS Source.

Comment: The selection of DMLC when `transacted` was implemented to resolve [this JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-2767). Use of DMLC without transacted is not recommended.

Comment: I knew I am missing something simple and that was it.    With acknowledge=transacted, I see DMLC was created and subscription is durable.    Thanks much Artem & Gary!